# Is it possible for a primary key to have more than 2 foreign keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was also wondering if it's possible for a relation to have multiple foreign keys?

I have an entity called `partnership` which I wanted to be a relation, but it has at least 5 or so foreign keys, so I don't know what to do.

```
Partnership(
   #team_num,
   #institute_num,
   #mode_cod, object,
   #teammember_num,
   #institutemember_num
)
```

Comment: Yes.  There is no (practical) limit on the number of keys in a primary key relationships.  That said, I would encourage you to have a `serial` primary key and just declare the other columns as `unique` (and `not null`).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: actually `identity` is preferred over `serial` these days: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Thank you for letting me know.  You may need to remind me again sometime.  I do with the syntax were a bit shorter than `generated always as identity` -- have the powers that be considered SQL Server's shortcut?

Comment: I don't think they will ever use the non-standard syntax used by Microsoft. After all `generated always as identity` is the way it's defined in the SQL standard - it's not something the Postgres devs came up with out of thin air